# access column reference to summarise column using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been trying to find a way to iterate through columns in a dataframe using `dplyr` so I can perform operations on each column. I dont quite understand how to reference each column however without hardcoding the column name.

For example, this would get column means using apply:
    apply(exampledf,2,function(x){mean(x)})

Note the reference to the column itself `x` that can passed to the function. Is there something similar that I am missing in `dplyr`?

The specific task I am trying to do (along with my non-working dplyr code) is to create a new column that contains `column_mean(column_sd)`:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
exampledf<- as.data.frame(matrix(ceiling(runif(16,0,50)), ncol=4))
colnames(exampledf)<-c("c1","c2","c3","c4")
row.names(exampledf)<-c("r1","r2","r3","r4")
exampledf%>%group_by(exampledf$c1)%>%mutate(meanSD=paste(mean()+"("+sd()+")"))
```

GOAL

```
   c1 c2 c3 c4 meanSD
r1 46 33 33 47 37.50(15.15)
r2 47 26 36 13 25.75(13.30)
r3 15 37 23 24 32.00(6.16)
r4 42  7 36 48 33.00(17.33)
```

Comment: sorry about that, fixed the goal to match the seed

Comment: I think what you're doing is not a good fit for a data.frame much less for dplyr. Anyway, you can use `apply` with `.` in place of the data.frame: `exampledf %>% mutate(m = rowMeans(.), sd = apply(.,1,sd))`

Comment: Thanks, that works great. Why is this not a good fit for a dataframe? Is there something else I should use? My output needs to be a table of some sort.

Comment: I guess if you're making this as a table for printing in an article, a data.frame might not be the worst way to go, but if you're doing per-row operations as part of your analysis, you should probably be using a matrix, I think.

Comment: if I was using a matrix would it change how you did any of these operations? I have no problem changing it to a dataframe afterward, or did I miss your point?

Comment: I meant that data.frames are designed for use with data of mixed types (string, integer, float); while if you have data that is all of one type, you should probably be using a `matrix`, the simplest structure for such cases and one for which many optimized functions are available, like `rowMeans`. If you call `rowMeans` on a data.frame, it is coerced to a matrix anyways, which is costly. If you start with a matrix, you can also use things like `rowSds` in the `matrixStats` package. Generally, if you find yourself doing `apply(DF, 1, fun)`, you probably should use a matrix.

Comment: oooh thanks I didnt know that!